# Crontab shell scripting PHP test

Tags: php, shell, pipe, cron

Here is my script (autoRun.sh, and it is executable):

```
date >> testResults.txt
php DatabaseTest.php >> testResults.txt
```

And here is my crontab file:

```
30 11 * * * /Users/myName/Desktop/autoRun.sh
```

`DatabaseTest.php` and `testResults.txt` both exist on the desktop with `autoRun.sh`, but when I check my text file, nothing is in it and the time has already passed.

Any suggestions on changes I need to make to my files?

Comment: It's probably a difference between your interactive login environment and the environment your cron job runs in.  php might not be on your path and the working directory might be different in the cron environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the direct path to your php executable, something like

```
/usr/bin/php
```

You can check where you're running php on the command line:

```
which php
```

When you run the shell script using cron, it's usually a system user running the script, and that user doesn't have the same environment setup.

Comment: That was what the issue was. Thanks!